# spark-submit how to specify that dependent libraries are inside application's jar

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a small test app for Spark 2.1.0 running as a 2 worker cluster on my computer and packaging dependent libraries inside my application's jar file. How can I tell Spark during spark-submit that libraries inside applications's jar file? Otherwise I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Or should dependent libraries copied to Spark?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spark does not support the "libraries inside app jar" feature supported by MapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

To add external libraries add application jar in below directories

`spark.driver.extraLibraryPath
spark.driver.extraClassPath

spark.executor.extraClassPath

spark.executor.extraLibraryPath`

You can find path of above directories in /etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-defaults.conf file

Comment: So spark by itself is not looking inside the jar?

Comment: You need to check how you are packaging the application jar. I assume you are using maven or sbt to build your jar. Build and packaging is completing successfully?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I there something special should be in the jar? All libraries are in the jar's root.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to build an uber jar - where all your dependencies in pom will be added into your jar.

The other and best way is -

1. Make the spark specific jars available on the cluster classpath(in
   pom make them as provided scope)
2. Any third party libraries can be
   added using "--jars /fullpath/your.jar" for spark submit or by
   spark.driver.extraLibraryPath, spark.driver.extraClassPath,
   spark.executor.extraClassPath, spark.executor.extraLibraryPath as
   mentioned above.

Comment: I build jur with all dependencies but spark does not find these on load.